# Changing DOMNode tag name creating anomalies within the saved HTML

Tags: php, wordpress, dom

In the process of making a Wordpress post parser for my personal website but hitting some behaviour I can't explain.

Here's the code:

```
// Wordpress uses <p></p> sections for new lines
$sections = $doc->getElementsByTagName('p');

foreach ($sections as $section) 
{
    $hasChilderen = $section->hasChildNodes();
    $contents = $section->nodeValue; 

    // If we have text, assume we are a paragraph (for the time being)
    if (!empty($contents))
    {
        $section->setAttribute('class', 'post-inner-content-paragraph');
    }
    elseif ($hasChilderen)
    {
        $section->setAttribute('class', 'post-inner-content-media');
        $section = change_tag_name($section, 'div');

        $imgs = $section->getElementsByTagName('img');
        foreach ($imgs as $img)
        {
            $img->removeAttribute('class');
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $section->setAttribute('class', 'post-inner-content-empty');
    }        
}
```

`change_tag_name`:

```
function change_tag_name($node, $name) 
{
    $doc = $node->ownerDocument;

    $newnode = $doc->createElement($name);

    foreach ($node->childNodes as $child)
    {
        $child = $doc->importNode($child, true);
        $newnode->appendChild($child);
    }

    if ($node->hasAttributes())
    {
        foreach ($node->attributes as $attr) 
            {
                $name = $attr->nodeName;
                $value = $attr->nodeValue;
                $newnode->setAttribute($name, $value);
            }
    }

    $node->parentNode->replaceChild($newnode, $node);

    return $newnode;
}
```

There's no way for a `<p>` block to passed as a section and NOT get an attribute assigned to it, however:

[image: Parsed post]

The highlighted `<p>` block doesn't have a class!

Here's the HTML loaded into the `DOMDocument` `$dom`: http://pastebin.com/biVSyWn9

Here's the HTML leaving my parse function: http://pastebin.com/RhzgeWAS

I can't detect any reason why this particular `<p>` block isn't being set a class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution

You have to traverse the node list backwards in order to make the kind of changes I want to do. crnix's answer helped identify that the problem occured with `replaceChild` within the `change_tag_name` function. Changing my `foreach` loop to the following fixed my issue:

```
$sections = $doc->getElementsByTagName('p');
$i = $sections->length - 1;
while ($i > -1)
{
    $section = $sections->item($i);

    // Change tag name of section

    $i--;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran this using DOMDocument (assuming that you're using it for parsing). I also commented out your change_tag_name function since the source code for that was not posted. 
It works. I got `class` attributes added to all the `<p>` tags.

Now, as to why it doesn't work for you, I can think of only two reasons:

- The end tag of the `<p>` just before the one that doesn't work is not recognized due to some reason. Because of this, the parser reads the next `<p>` tag as part of the previous `<p>`.
- The `change_tag_name` function may be doing something which it is not intended to do (highly unlikely, but that is something you may want to rule out).

Comment: I wouldn't know if the `change_tag_name` function would cause this, here's the code: http://pastebin.com/eWXjckRa It certainly might be though, since the `p` with this issues is directly after the previous `p` which was changed to do `div`

Comment: Yes, it is indeed the change_tag_name function that messes things up. I just ran it again with your change_tag_name function, and I got the same result as yours.

Comment: I've found the cause! The problem you need to traverse the node list backwards if you're making changes. So, changing the code to the following fixes the issue: http://i.imgur.com/GZ4hRID.png Hooray! Thanks for the help.